# GraphQL returns null on successful mutation INSERT SQL instead of a value

Tags: postgresql, typescript, graphql, mutation, graphiql

```
const resolver= {
    Query: {
        EventsQuery: async () => {
            return await db.select('*').from('events')
        },
    },
    Mutation: {
        AddEventMutation: async (_: any, input) => {
        return await db('events').returning('event_name').insert([
                {
                    event_name: input.event_name,
                    event_venue: input.event_venue
                }
            ]).then((name) => {
                console.log(name)   // value is displayed 
                return name
            })
        },  
    },
}
```

I have a GraphQL server that connects to the PostgreSQL DB and I am performing an INSERT SQL to add item in to the db. I am using Knex.js query builder and the above query inserts data into the table and returns `event_name`. Data was inserted into the db but in GraphiQL I am getting this response. I think it should return a value instead of null.

```
{
  "data": {
    "AddEventMutation": {
      "event_name": null
    }
  }
}
```

This is how I added the data into the db from GraphiQL.

```
mutation{
  AddEventMutation(event_name: "Mutation", event_date: "1002") {
    event_name
  } 
}
```

Can anyone tell me what went wrong? If getting the null value is correct, how does the client know if the mutation operation is a success or not? I am still experimenting and confused.

Comment: `AddEventMutation`'s type is an object type with an `event_name` field. So the resolver should return an object with an `event_name` property. Instead you're returning a string, which *is* an object but does not have an `event_name` property.

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate, those questions are not using postgresql and whatever result we get is different. But anyway, based on your comment here I did some other way and got it to work. Thanks